# Suggestion for software to analyze data from social media- please advise

Tags: corpora, software

I am searching urgent for a software that I can use to analyse corpora. In short, I would like to have a look at collocations, ellipsis, frequencies, concordances etc. I also want to search for themes and then accordingly to be able to assign the data different categories, so that I am able to work further on these. For overview of the data I tried to upload it in AntConc, but it is not working (though that the data is less than 400MB). I read about QDAMiner, didn’t understand however if WordStat is part of it or it can run separately (or what I need in general). Do you have any comments or suggestions about a program I can use? I am grateful for every information

EDIT: I would like to carry out mostly qualitative analysis, so the program doesn't have to do all analysis automatically, but to offer tools/features which can help me analyze the data.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a software that can do quite a lot. Many of the tasks you are asking for can be done with Python NLTK, for pointers to some tutorial see [TeLeMaCo](http://fedora.clarin-d.uni-saarland.de/hub/kwsearch/NLTK/0/) hosted by the CLARIN-D centra at Saarland University. For themes, a topic model can be of help, see [here for tutorials on topic modelling](http://fedora.clarin-d.uni-saarland.de/hub/kwsearch/topic%20model/0/).

I am not aware of any software that can annotate ellipsis automatically (in any language).

EDIT: In response to the comment, there is another relevant software, namely the Corpus Query Processor and its web fontend [CQPweb](http://cwb.sourceforge.net/cqpweb.php). Again, there are some tutorials linked from [TeLeMaCo](https://fedora.clarin-d.uni-saarland.de/hub/kwsearch/CQPweb/0/).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I plan to carry out the analysis mostly manually. I have just edited my question, thank you for the information. Basically, except the trivial features -to be able to produce collocations, frequencies, concordances etc., the program should allow me to assign (manually) categories to segments of the corpus and then be able to work with them structured.